# CSS: Can I add ease transition to image color change hover effect?

Tags: css, hover, transition, opacity, easing

I created a simple effect that causes an image to change color on hover. Now I want to add transition-timing-function properties so the color transition fades in and out rather than an instant change, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out 1s;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out 1s;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out 1s;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
  div:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: Indigo;
  opacity: 0.4;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The `::after` selector works as a separate element, so having the transitions on the `div` won't work, they need to be applied to the `::after`.
2. The `:hover::after` selector needs something to transition *from*.

This should work:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div::after {
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-out 1s;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out 1s;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.4;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}
div:hover::after {
  background-color: Indigo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DisgruntledGoat!

Answer (score 0):

Somebody also shared this code with me, which seems to do the same thing by wrapping the image in a span class:

```
.imghov {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.13ss linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.imghov img {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.imghov:hover {
  background-color: indigo;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

imghov:hover,
.imghov:hover img {
  opacity: 0.6;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the transitions on the `:hover` state, if they are the same as the non-hover state. Also only the `-ms-` prefixed one is required now, Opera/Firefox/Webkit all support the regular syntax.